# Generic style targettype

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I have a common style shared between more then one type of control (TextBox and Xceed's LongUpDown / DoubleUpDown).

The style is named (or keyed?) and I don't want it to apply automatically to all controls of the target type.

I have no idea which is the closest Base Type for all these controls, so I thought I could try to set the TargetType to UIElement, but VS seems to not recognize it.

**How can I set the TargetType to UIElement?**

Style:

```
<Style TargetType="TextBox" x:Key="TextFieldEntry">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="AliceBlue" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsDirty}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="#FFF9D74B" />
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsDirty}" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="#FF98F329" />
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Control:

```
 Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=TextFieldEntry}"
```

Comment: You can try with `TargetType="Control"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `TargetType` to `UIElement` but it won't work because the `BorderBrush` and the `Background` property which are used in your style both defined on the [`System.Windows.Controls.Control` class.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.aspx) and not on the `UIElement`.

So you just need to set the `TargetType` to `Control` to make it work:

```
<Style TargetType="Control" x:Key="TextFieldEntry">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="AliceBlue" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsDirty}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="#FFF9D74B" />
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsDirty}" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="#FF98F329" />
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```